# My React Project Shows Weird Behavior-Components load only sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My React project is acting weirdly, i.e, a component is rendered only sometimes. At other times, it doesn't render completely even though elements like buttons are rendered. Also sometimes the css on other pages changes automatically. I can't seem to figure out what is happening.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Homes.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Home extends Component {
  state = { value: "" };
  handleInp = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSub = () => {
    this.state.value === ""
      ? alert("Enter a String!")
      : console.log(this.state.value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="whole">
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="headi ">Enter the String</h1>
          <input
            className="in"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={(evt) => this.handleInp(evt)}
            placeholder="Enter the string"
          />
          <Link to={"/edit/" + this.state.value}>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary but m-3 btn-sm"
              id="but"
              onClick={this.handleSub}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Above is the Home component, which is showing this behavior.

This thing was working perfectly until a point of time. I did not change anything in the code. But then, the Home component stopped working in the right way(without showing any error)

Comment: it sounds like you are just getting css conflicts - when you do `import "./Homes.css"` it's not "scoped" to this component, to do that you need to use [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)

Comment: Thanks so much! Had been hung up on this for quite some time